# How to use npm view to find versions within a range?

Tags: npm

`npm view some-pkg versions` will list all versions, and `npm view some-pkg@latest version` will show the latest version. But is there a command for querying for the latest version in a *specific semver range*, such as `6.2.x`?

Answer (score 1):

This seems close (using the `@storybook/preact` package):

```
$ npm view @storybook/preact@'6.2.x' version
undefined@6.2.2 '6.2.2'
undefined@6.2.3 '6.2.3'
undefined@6.2.0 '6.2.0'
undefined@6.2.1 '6.2.1'
undefined@6.2.8 '6.2.8'
undefined@6.2.9 '6.2.9'
undefined@6.2.6 '6.2.6'
undefined@6.2.7 '6.2.7'
undefined@6.2.4 '6.2.4'
undefined@6.2.5 '6.2.5'
```

Note the versions are not sorted in order.